# How to overwrite file on server

Tags: java, linux, server

I made a game and now I want to add a global Highscore. I can reach the file with an url "http://example.com/apps/score". I have no problem reading the file. But I cant overwrite it and add new scores. The file and the folder has rwxrwxrwx. I have no idea what I am doing wrong.
This is what I tried:

```
public void updateScore() {
    try {

        URLConnection connection = url.openConnection();
        connection.setDoOutput(true);
        Writer wr = new OutputStreamWriter(connection.getOutputStream());

        String text="";
        for (int i = 0; i < alScores.size(); i++) {
            text+=alScores.get(i).getName()+"¨"+alScores.get(i).getScore()+"\n";
        }

        wr.write(text);
        wr.flush();
        connection.getInputStream().close();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}
```

Comment: What you have is a static web page, whereas you'd need a dynamic web page that would read the scores from a database for example. It gets a bit too broad, and there's plenty of different options on how to do it.

Answer (score 0):

You would need some kind of a web service that would accept a new score and update the file accordingly. This would happen on the serverside though.

Right now you are just sending some data to the server that it is probably not even listening to.

Comment: The best way is , write a WCF for the same.

Comment: Is there a tutorial out there?

Comment: @unrealwombat if you want to use java for this, you could pick the Spark framework and listen for HTTP POST requests on the server. You can find tutorials for Spark on their homepage: sparkjava.com